# OSSRH release not replicating to maven central

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

3 days ago, I successfully released version 2.0.2 of a maven archetype to OSSRH and it shows up in the OSSRH archetype catalog and can be downloaded from OSS releases (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/edu/uchicago/mpcs53013/hdfs-ingest-weather-archetype/2.0.2/)

However, if I look in Maven Central, it still shows only version 2.0.1. Shouldn't it be visible after 3 days. Is there a way I can force a sync?[image]

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: mvnrepository.com is **NOT** Maven Central. Maven Central is here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ etc. Or https://search.maven.org

Answer (score 1):

There is:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/uchicago/mpcs53013/hdfs-ingest-weather-archetype/2.0.2/

After release to Central Repository by sonatype your artefact should be visible after a few hours:
http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html#releasing-to-central

If you have some problem you can check status of sonatype services:
http://status.sonatype.com/

You can also create issue for maven Central Repository:
http://central.sonatype.org/pages/help.html

Mvnrepository is some sort of indexing many maven repository in one place. One of indexing is Central Repository. So if something is wrong with mvnrepository - please contact with support of this site.

Comment: Thanks. Still, if you don't mind a question, how come it isn't showing at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.uchicago.mpcs53013/hdfs-ingest-weather-archetype? That is still only showing 2.0.1 (as in the screenshot) even though it has been 3 days since submitting.